# Handling changes to a program's update process

Tags: c#, updates

I have an application that has its own update process.  I wrote my own because I did not want to use ClickOnce and did not know about Squirrel at the time.  The update process is as follows:

- Archive current version
- Download ZIP package from remote location
- Inspect manifest file for file version and compare to determine if an update exists
- Extract ZIP contents into a staging location
- Rename the files being replaced with _Delete appended at the end
- Copy the files from staging to root
- Delete staging directory

I only copy over DLL files, the EXE, and the MANIFEST file.  The other files are various settings files that I didn't want to overwrite.

There are some requested features that would require adding to one of the settings files but I don't know how to go about providing such a feature with the current update process.  The only thing I can think of is to establish some sort of "minimum version" feature in the update process so before you can go from version A to C you have to download B first.  Then have separate releases where one is for the update process and the next is the requested feature.

One last item is that these are not automatic updates.  A user opts in by explicitly checking for updates and saying they want to update if one exists.  There is only one ZIP file in the remote location instead of a ZIP file for each version released.

Any ideas on how I should go about these changes?  There is a small user base right now so whatever it takes to be in a good spot I'm willing to hear about.

Comment: Not clear what help you are looking for.  You have a custom update process your audience knows nothing about.

Comment: In order to support a new feature I need to make changes to my update process.  Do you work around the limitations of whatever that process is so it doesn't need to change, do you make multiple updates (first being something that lays the groundwork for a later update), or is there another way I'm not thinking of?  If it makes more sense I can delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is your update process is able to override binary files and now it needs to "merge" text files (the settings) such as new settings are added next to existing settings without overriding the values of the existing settings.

In this case I suggest you use default values for new settings. Here's an example:

- in version 1.0 you deliver the settings for the database connection.
- in version 1.1 you add a new setting to control the `timeout` and update the settings file. Your code should check if this value already exists in the setting file and use it if it is there, otherwise set it to a default value of your choosing - say 5 seconds; this is stored in memory (hardcoded). Optionally you can write this value into the settings file if it's not there, to let the user know there is a new setting available.

What this buys you:

- users who install 1.1 (without having previously installed 1.0) get the setting file with the `timeout` set to 5 seconds.
- users who upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1 keep their existing settings file, which you may or may not update when 1.1 runs
- you can update from any version to latest, because your code always defines default value for settings even if they are not present in the settings file.

Comment: I'm thinking of having these settings files become auto-generated if they don't exist but still use your versioning idea from your answer.  The only difference is the files aren't part of the package (which I think makes sense because they are unique to each individual install anyway).